# PHP Duck Sample - Head First - Design Patterns - Chapter One

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface

This is the first question I ask from many others to come.

Someone here might call me crazy because I'm following the mentioned book in the question's Title using PHP-OO.

At the first chapter, the authors introduce a simple project called 'SimUDuck' and, although I've reproduced the same in Java, I was wondering to reproduce the same using PHP.

At the end, the SimUDuck's project creates two (2) interfaces (FlyBehavior and QuackBehavior), more than five (5) classes implementing those interfaces (e.g. FlyWithWings(), Quack() etc), an abstract class called Duck and three (3) or four (4) different ducks species classes extending Duck (Mallard, HeadRedDuck, RubberDuck etc), just to demonstrate how important is to program for interface.

To simulate the Java main method environment, I've created a PHP class called MiniDuckSimulator, including the function 'public static function main()' and in the same script I've added "MiniDuckSimulator::main();". The script works without errors.

The intriguing issue is that without call any QuackBehavior::quack() implemented method, the echo 'Quack!quack!' appears. Those who has read this book knows what I'm talking about.

Note: Below is a particular part of the script:

---

```
interface FlyBehavior {
    public function fly();
}
```

---

```
interface QuackBehavior {
    public function quack();
}
```

---

```
include_once 'FlyBehavior.php';

class FlyWithWings implements FlyBehavior {

    public function fly() {
        echo 'I'm flying!<br />';
    }

}
```

---

```
include_once 'QuackBehavior.php';

class Quack implements QuackBehavior {

    public function quack() {
        echo 'Quack!<br />';
    }
}
```

---

```
abstract class Duck {

    protected $flyBehavior;
    protected $quackBehavior;

    function  __construct() {
    }

    public function performFly(){
        $this->flyBehavior->fly();

    }

    public function performQuack(){
        $this->quackBehavior->quack();

    }

    public function setFlyBehavior($flyBehavior){
        $this->flyBehavior = $flyBehavior;
    }

    public function swim(){
        echo "All the ducks float, including the decoy!<br />";
    }
}
```

---

```
include_once 'Duck.php';
include_once 'FlyWithWings.php';
include_once 'Quack.php';

class Mallard extends Duck {

    function __construct() {
        $this->flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
        $this->quackBehavior = new Quack();
    }

}
```

---

```
class MiniDuckSimulator {
    public static function main(){
        $mallard = new Mallard();
        $mallard->performFly();
    }

}

MiniDuckSimulator::main();
```

---

Thanks in advance.

LucDaher.

Comment: My eyes've been hurt by reading the text :-S

Comment: Sorry for that. I would make it short but would miss some important information for those who are interested to help me.

Comment: A double "quack" is way unhelpful. It could be the same method called twice, or a method and that of the class parent. I'd add some text like "quack-rubber" and "quack mallard" etc.

Comment: Is it better???? Now, about "code snippets" it would be impossible because it's about 10 different files. What I would do is to attach those file somewhere.

Comment: Don't bother... It's a pleasure. See if the issue became more illustrative.

Comment: About the echo problem, forgive me, it's because I'm brazilian and the string within the echo statement would be 'Estou voando!' and for make more suitable for those who is intending to help me, I have translated to english at the moment I past the script here and I forgot to replace to double quote. A can not visualize when you say "you calling a non-static function", sorry.

Comment: Forgive me again. Now I know what you are talking about the non-static function. Again, I must have forgotten to past the "static" word before function at "public function main()".

Comment: One of our fellow bellow (nickname Macek) has answered the question. The problem was the Quack class had the method quack() and, as the PHP will treat any method that has the same name as the class as the class constructor, when I called "$mallard = new Quack()" the quack() method content will be executed. What I did was simple... change the class name to NormalClass, thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing `Quack!<br />` output is because of this:

```
class Quack implements QuackBehavior {

    public function quack() {
        echo 'Quack!<br />';
    }
}
```

**Here's your problem:** If you simply run `new Quack();` the `quack()` method is automatically being executed by php as a constructor because it is the same name as your class. -- I see you referenced Java in your question, so this shouldn't be a foreign concept to you.

```
new Quack(); // => Quack!<br />
```

---

### A potentially better way

```
<?php

interface CanFly {
  public function fly();
}

interface CanQuack {
  public function quack();
}

abstract class Duck implements CanFly, CanQuack {

  protected $color = "DEFAULT"

  public function fly(){
    echo "I'm flying with my {$this->color} wings\n";
  }

  public function quack(){
    echo "I'm quacking\n";
  }

  public function swim(){
    echo "I'm swimming\n";
  }
}

class Mallard extends Duck {

  public function __construct(){
    $this->color = "green";
  }

  public function quack(){
    echo "My quack sounds more like a honk\n";
  }
}

$m = new Mallard();
$m->fly();
$m->quack();
$m->swim();

?>
```

Output

```
I'm flying with my green wings
My quack sounds more like a honk
I'm swimming
```

Comment: About the echo mistake, I've already explained why. It's because I'm brazilian and in portuguese we say 'Estou voando!' without using the single quote within the string and after I paste I translated the string to english. Don't bother about the second "quack!". I have edited the string content to reproduce just one "quack" (It's to much quack for me already!!!! :). About the actual code you have mentioned, the code I pasted is the actual code.

Comment: I can't help you if you're not going to read the answer. The reason you're seeing a `Quack!<br />` is because you have a function `quack()` named the same thing as the `Quack` class and php is automatically treating that as a constructor. I've added even some more edits that may help you see how to do this in a potentially better way...

Comment: Sorry... I saw now, I didn't see the answer you gave after the horizontal line, and you are absolutely right. Thank you very much. I have forgotten that PHP will treat any method with the same name as the class as the class constructor. What I did was to rename the class Quack as NormalQuack and entire script worked well. Thank you very much one more time.

Comment: I think this is not a better way because he is talking about the book Head First - Design Patterns, on the book this example about not implementing quack and flying inside the duck class because a rubber duck cannot fly for example. They suggest creating interfaces and classes and for this actions and then use the objects in the constructor of the Duck class.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would personally assume that I've overlooked something when saying that an echo is being reached in the code without a call to that method.  I can't see a way that this would be possible.

Reanalyze your code and look for a sneaky way that your echo 'Quack!quack!' is being reached.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick reply. Although might be insufficient, but below is the "function main()" content:         $mallard = new Mallard();
$mallard->performFly(); //nothing more.

Comment: First off, the above comments are asking you to break up your question, not to make it smaller.  It's too hard to read.  Second, ducks have been known to quack when being born or flying.  I joke.  But seriously, there has to be something calling your method that contains the 'echo' statement.  it won't call itself.  Something must be overlooked.

Comment: I hope the question became better to read now. If you've read the book and tested the same sample using Java (I believe you did), the only thing you have to do is to replace the Java namespace (e.g. "System.out.println", void) and declaration with PHP, nothing more. (Of course if you have available time for that).

Comment: I haven't read the book.  My answer was a suggestion to approach your problem with critical thinking.  Encounter issue --> assume mistake on your part --> find and fix mistake.  I wish I could help you more.

Comment: "Encounter issue -->" I tried!!! "assume mistake on your part -->" I'm assuming since yesterday and I didn't find the solution and this is one of the reasons why I asked this question. "find and fix mistake" if I haven't exhausted all the possibilities that came within my mind, again, I haven't ask this question and brought so many doubts in the members minds.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line:

```
echo 'Quack!<br />';
```

Do you see any more quacks? If so, then there is an echo/exit/die in your code with this string!

Comment: It's just one quack guys!!! I have edited the echo result to reproduce just one. It's because at the book sample, the authors, as they like ducks to much, they wrote the 'System.out.println' with two (2) "quacks!". Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you have the class with the same name of the method, the PHP consider it as a constructor. This is already deprecated in php 7 and it will be discontinued soon. You can see it on the online documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php