# php interface polymorph cannot trace why function is performed

Tags: php, algorithm, design-patterns

I am testing using interfaces and php.  I was able to find code to re-create the duck design problems in the "Head First Design Patterns" from Java to Perl with some help of the following link:

http://idhana.com/2011/10/12/design-pattern-strategy-in-php/

However, I noticed that the creator change the name of the quack() algorithm to "Quacker()".  I did not know why this happened, but as it turns out it may explain my problem.

When I keep the name of the algorithm to Quack, and not Quacker, the instance of the inherited class not only set's the behaviour but commits it!! (prints some text I don't want to see until I order the duck to do so)

I have two ducks to test this out.  One used the Quack() and another QuackNormally().  I have created the files into Duck_That_Quacks_Prematurely_At_Birth.php to show that this instance of the Duck class uses the behaviour I don't understand and the Duck_That_Quacks_Normally.php that uses the QuackNormally() algorithm.

```
<?php

abstract class Duck
{
    protected $quackBehavior;

    public function performQuack()
    {
        $this->quackBehavior->quack();
    }
}
?>
<?php

include_once("QuackNormally.php");

class Duck_That_Quacks_Normally extends Duck
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->quackBehavior = new QuackNormally();
    }

}

?>
<?php

include_once("Quack.php");

class Duck_That_Quacks_Prematurely_At_Birth extends Duck
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->quackBehavior = new Quack();
    }
}

?>

<?php

interface QuackBehavior
{
    public function quack();
}

?>
<?php

include_once ("QuackBehavior.php");

class QuackNormally implements QuackBehavior
{
    public function quack()
    {
        echo ("This is a normal quack that you should not hear until ordered.");
    }
}
<?php

include_once ("QuackBehavior.php");

class Quack implements QuackBehavior
{
    public function quack()
    {
        echo ("QUACK !!! I can't stop talking once created !!!");
    }
}

?>

<?php

include_once ("Duck.php");
include_once ("Duck_That_Quacks_Prematurely_At_Birth.php");
include_once ("Duck_That_Quacks_Normally.php");

echo "<html>";

echo "Duck_That_Quacks_Prematurely_At_Birth being created:<br/>";
$test_duck = new Duck_That_Quacks_Prematurely_At_Birth();
#echo "Start of a break line:<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "Duck_That_Quacks_Normally being created:<br/>";
$control_duck = new Duck_That_Quacks_Normally();
#echo "Start of a break line:<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "Duck_That_Quacks_Prematurely_At_Birth wants to say something:<br/>";
$test_duck->performQuack();
#echo "Start of a break line:<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "Duck_That_Quacks_Normally wants to say something:<br/>";
$control_duck->performQuack();
#echo "Start of a break line:<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "</html>";

?>
```

My best bet is the the name - quack() of the duck class is clobbering with the name of the algorithms that share the same name - Quack().  Yet, PHP is case-senstive, so I honestly don't know what is going on.

I apologize for vocabulary that is alien or annoying.  This is my first post.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this serious? I'm only asking cos im ROFL!

Comment: Is it funny because of the names used or funny because the answer is obvious?

Comment: I am going with "PHP is broke, 'Quack'=='quack'" philosphy..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664572/php-duck-sample-head-first-design-patterns-chapter-one?rq=1